# Unable to create Phpmyadmin on VPS

Tags: phpmyadmin, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to setup wordpress on my server. And I want to create Phpmyadmin on my VPS. I followed this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/janikvonrotz/9320678), and I managed to get it work to the extent where I visit the public ip it shows me the `info.php` correctly.

When I moved to the stage of installing phpmyadmin, I did everything as said in the tutorial. But when I vist `myipaddress/phpmyadmin` I'm getting:

```
404 Not Found
ngnix/1.4.6/ubuntu
```

N:B during the phpmyadmin installation I selected lightpd.

How can I make phpmyadmin work? I not familiar with php.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ngnix (as evidenced by the error message) but selected lightpd when prompted by dpkg, you can just reconfigure the package to use ngnix instead. dpkg prompts you so that it can automatically configure which server you'll use.

`dpkg-reconfigure --plow phpmyadmin`